# In BigQuery, how do I output my ARRAY_AGG as as several smaller arrays?

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

Say that I have a table with two columns, state and social security number. If you perform the following query

```
SELECT STATE, ARRAY_AGG(SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER) FROM {table} GROUP BY STATE
```

You'll end up with 50 giant arrays. For export purposes, these giant arrays are too big, so instead, I'd like to end up with a bunch of smaller arrays instead. So instead of:

```
New York: [array of 20 million],
```

I'd like...

```
New York: [Array of 1 million]
New York: [Array of 1 million]
New York: [Array of 1 million]
...
```

When I tried

```
SELECT STATE, ARRAY_AGG(SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER LIMIT 1000000) FROM {table} GROUP BY STATE
```

I just ended up with a single array of one million instead of the chunking that I'm looking for. What's the best way to accomplish this?

I'm also wondering whether I should just group by regularly and then try to split arrays or if it would be more performant to try to do it inside the grouping by stage in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is something like:

```
SELECT STATE, rn/1000000, ARRAY_AGG(SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER) 
FROM 
 (SELECT STATE, SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY STATE ORDER BY SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER) rn
 FROM {table}) sq
GROUP BY STATE, rn/1000000
```

The idea is that integer division uses a floor, so the first million records per state have rn/1000000 = 0, the next million per state have rn/1000000 = 1 and so forth, so grouping by that as well as state gets you up to one million records per group.

Depending on your existing inner query (if `{table}` isn't a literal table), you could maybe add the `row_number` column there instead of adding an additional subquery. Depending on what you know about your indexes or how you want the divisions ordered, the `ORDER BY SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER` could be adjusted.